# A question about a Bus Transceiver operation

Tags: datasheet

Regarding [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74axc4t774.pdf?ts=1682122088779) bus transceiver: if VCCA is fed with 3.3V and VCCB is fed with 1.8V, does that mean a 1.7V input signal transferred from B to A will be obtained as 3.3V at A pin? And similarly a 3.0V output signal transferred from A to B will be obtained as 1.8V at B pin?

[image]

Comment: That’s the general idea.